# How to get parent site lists

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, client-object-model

I am using JavaScript on a subsite to retrieve items from a list which is on the parent site. When I use this code:

```
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var lists = clientContext.get_site().get_rootWeb().get_lists();
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
```

A message on subsite home says, this list does not exist on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var rootWeb = clientContext.get_site.get_rootWeb();
var oList = rootWeb.get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
```